# Professional Databases and Historical Games

Tags: history, database

I have tried to look for historical chess games (i.e. 19th century to early 20th century). I usually use Chessbase online database and `chessgames.com`.

I have never paid for a database or database subscription, but I was wondering if anyone knows whether they tend to have more complete historical games than the free options available on these chess websites?

Comment: Or, is there a database that is best for historical games?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at https://chess-db.com/public/index.jsp

This website has historical players like: Morphy, Marshall, Steinitz, Bird. You can download all their games.